# Google Scholar does not return a report of 2016 when using as custom range 2016-2023

Tags: google-scholar, literature-review, literature-search, grey-literature

When searching for the string "open* education*" selecting Anytime, Google Scholar returns as 4th result "Opening up education: A support framework for higher education institutions" of 2016. When searching for the string "open* education*" selecting as Custom Range 2016-2023, Google Scholar does not return this report. How is this possible?

Comment: Google scholar is a commercial tool developed by Alphabet, the biggest advertising company in the world. Ask them and please report back your findings!

Answer (score 2):

Search results are different depending on who is logged in and other factors.

When I try your first search, I don't get that result on the first page. To ensure I get it on the first page, I added "support" as an additional search term, and then your result shows up as the first result. But also, when I try your second search plus "support," that paper still shows up as the first result.

So I think it's still returning your paper, just not on the first page.

Try navigating through the pages of results by clicking Next at the bottom.

Comment: Re your last sentence: my search agrees with your prediction. The article mentioned by the OP is, in the second search, reported on page 4 ... not the 4th result.

Comment: To the OP of the question, your claim "_Google Scholar does not return this report._" is false. Please refine your search and don't jump to the conclusion.